# The set $\{\|f\|_\alpha \leq 1 \}$ has compact closure in $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

> Recall the Holder norm  $(0<\alpha\leq 1) $
>   $$\|f\|_\alpha = \max\bigg\{ |f(x)| +
>  \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} : x,y \in [0,1], x\neq y\bigg\}$$
>
> I want to show that the set $\mathcal F :=\{ \|f\|_\alpha \leq 1 \}$ has a
>   compact closure in $C([0,1])$.

**My attempt:**

Using Arzela-Ascoli theorem, it suffice to show that $\mathcal F$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded which implies every sequence in $\mathcal F$ has a Cauchy subsequence.

Uniform boundedness follows from the fact that $\|f\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\alpha\leq 1$, then 
$$|f(x)| \leq 1 \text{ on } [0,1] \text{ for each } f\in \mathcal F.$$

For equicontinuity, let $x_0$ and $\epsilon$ be given, we use the fact that 
$$\frac{|f(x_0) - f(y)|}{|x_0-y|^\alpha} \leq \|f\|_\alpha \leq 1$$ 
to get $\delta = \epsilon^{1/\alpha}$. Then, for each $f\in \mathcal F$, we get
$$|f(x_0) - f(y)| \leq |x_0 - y|^\alpha \leq  (\epsilon^{1/\alpha})^\alpha = \epsilon.$$

is this okay? thank you very much!

Comment: Everything looks in order. Nice proof!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. You may want to compare it with the proofs of closely related results:

- [Is there a reference for compact imbedding of Hölder space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450028/)
- [How to show pre-compactness in Holder space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/547550/)
- [Proof of compactness of Lipschitz functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/762983/)